# How to upgrade VirtualBox 6.1.38 to 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

The VirtualBox that came from the Ubuntu repository while setting up my new 22.04 system a couple weeks back was virtualbox-qt 6.1.38. How can I upgrade the system to VirtualBox 7.0?

According to the Oracle VirtualBox web site, "*Version 6.1 will remain supported until December 2023*". That would be till like the end of this week.

Everything is working fine with a Win10 Pro VM on my new Ubuntu system except Android devices connected via USB are not recognized. A bunch of other stuff (Garmin GPS, Logitech Universal Remote, CD RW devices, etc.) are all working correctly over USB. Me thinks it best to upgrade to a VirtualBox version that hasn't reached end-of-life before proceeding on the Android issue.

Attempting to upgrade from the 7.0 .deb from the Oracle web site fails because of virtualbox-qt dependencies on the old VBox version. Step by step instructions would be appreciated. I really REALLY don't want to wipe out this new system having it so close to being fully operational.

Comment: Why do you need 7.0? Generally speaking part of the LTS deal is that the versions will remain stable over the lifetime of the release. Ubuntu (and Debian) will backport things when required.

Comment: When required? And who decides that? In my experience any software that has reached EOL is a good thing to stay away from. Even if "somebody" does promise to keep it running.

Comment: Honestly, it is easier to do it from the VirtualBox repos.  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: When required means when bugs are discovered, including security problems. When *somebody* is the vendor of your distribution, you already *have* decided to trust them, so why not trust them with this piece of software as well? The Ubuntu and Debian teams do this for a lot of software. Generally upgrading major versions is not done in either Debian or Ubuntu, rather the release teams spend time backporting fixes if the upstream has stopped supporting the version.

Comment: I've decided to trust nobody. I'm doing a proof of concept to determine if I can switch to LINUX from Win as my primary PC host OS. At this moment, given you description, I'd say LINUX isn't ready for prime time.

Comment: @cdawg357 I am unsure what made you take that decision so quickly, but Virtualbox 7 for Ubuntu 22.04 is available here https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.12/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

Comment: Ubuntu has never promised to be a drop-in replacement for Windows. There is a significant learning curve for Windows power-users. Much to re-learn. Like how to handle upgrades, how to handle EOL software, and how to establish trust. Several trustworthy experts have been trying to help you. Don't argue; listen to them.

Comment: I have already downloaded the 7.0 package. My question was and still is, what is the proper procedure to upgrade to it? With RPM, a properly built package is upgraded with "rpm -u".

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb` of course running that command from the directory where you downloaded the VirtualBox to.

Comment: @cdawg357 you plainly misunderstand. The point is to ensure stability. E.g. versions stay the same without breaking changes, and security and bug fixes are back ported. Yes, you don't get new features but you don't break existing.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, the steps are:

1. Uninstall the old version of VirtualBox:

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove virtualbox virtualbox-6.1
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Add the VirtualBox repository:

   ```
   echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | \  
   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
   ```
4. Add the repository key for VirtualBox:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnupg2
   wget -qO- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | \  
   sudo gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/virtualbox.gpg
   ```
5. And finally, install version 7 of Virtualbox:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install virtualbox-7.0
   ```

For details:

https://kifarunix.com/upgrade-virtualbox-6-x-to-virtualbox-7-x-on-ubuntu-debian/?expand_article=1